# Piranah CMS apply Permissions to Regions and Media instances

Tags: piranha-cms

I am reviewing Piranha CMS and really like the framework.

I am wondering how I can associate permissions to Regions and Media elements.

I was thinking that this may be easily accomplished through a custom extension but would like to know if this is the recommended approach.

What I'd like to do is to restrict rendering of a region if the current user's does not have access to it.  I was thinking I may be able to add a group GUID as the permission property of the region extension. If the permission property is an empty GUID then it will render the region otherwise the current user must be a member of the group that the region is associated to.

I would like to do the same for Media elements.

Cheers
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve both the region & media question with a custom extension, however I'm not really sure I follow why you would need it for the page region.

As regions are merely considered a "part of a page" there's no way to customize security for a single regions, it is set on the complete page.

As media is usually rendered in some context, as a page, there's currently no security setting for uploaded media. This however is a feature that could be added into the core framework as it could make sense for some use-cases.

Best regards

Håkan